# Declare by including its header, not by explicit declaration

Tags: c++

What does this piece of advice mean? It's from *The C++ Programming Language, Special Edition*.

> Declare standard library facilities by including its header, not by explicit declaration; §16.1.2.

Here's an extract from §16.1.2 that I believe is relevant:

> For a standard library
>   facility to be used its header must be
>   included. Writing out the relevant
>   declarations yourself is *not* a
>   standards-conforming alternative. The
>   reason is that some implementations
>   optimize compilation based on standard
>   header inclusion and others provide
>   optimized implementations of standard
>   library facilities triggered by the
>   headers. In general, implementers use
>   standard headers in ways programmers
>   cannot predict and shouldn’t have to
>   know about.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It means do this:

```
#include <cstdio>
```

Not this:

```
int printf(const char * format, ...);
```

You will often find people suggesting that doing the latter will lead to quicker compilation times (as the compiler won't have to read and interpret all the standard header files).

Comment: What about the technique where you declare a class instead of including the header. Is that shunned as well? It's seems to follow the same concept.

Comment: @someguy: If it's from the standard library, you should always get its declaration via the standard `#include`.

Comment: though there is <iosfwd> which muddies the waters slightly

Answer (score 1):

It simply means that you `#include` the standard libraries of c++, instead of any other other alternate way. This simply defines the standard to be followed. There has to be some protocol to its usage.